# Error while return json after use required_once("wp-load.php")

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api

i have try to develop one api using WP.

Bellow is my testing code.

```
    define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/wp-load.php');
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    wp();
    $PiBy180 = 0;
    $arr[0] = array("id"=>1,"name"=>"aaaa");
    $arr[1] = array("id"=>2,"name"=>"bbbb");
    echo json_encode($arr);die;
```

When i test it with postman it shows bellow output.
[image: wrong-output]

But if i comment `require_once` than i check it it works for me. But i need it becuase i have to call some wordpress function before i retun ajax json response. Please check bellow screenshot and code.

```
    define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
    //require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/wp-load.php');
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    //wp();
    $PiBy180 = 0;
    $arr[0] = array("id"=>1,"name"=>"aaaa");
    $arr[1] = array("id"=>2,"name"=>"bbbb");
    echo json_encode($arr);die;
```

[image: Required-output]

is there a way to load wp function without use require function. I have added custom file in my root folder of project.

Please suggest your solutions.

Comment: WordPress doesn't use eval. The output you have in the first case means your WordPress installation is infected by a virus.

Comment: @KAGGDesign i got solution and reason behind it. Its show eval wp-load.php load other files which having echo and in ajax response we can do echo once so i removed wp-load.php and make core php database function and access data from database

Comment: Whatever solution you find, your site is infected. No eval in whole WordPress code.

Comment: @KAGGDesign i will check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got solution.

I found that wp-load.php file include many other files and they file having having **echo** so just becuase of it return unwanted output. So finally i have made core php connection and access data from database and it works for me.

Here is my code.

```
ini_set("display_errors", 0);

    $host='localhost';
    $user='testuser';
    $password='testpass';
    $db='testdb';
    $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) or exit("Connection Error");
    $connection = mysql_select_db($db, $con);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM orders where customer_mail like '%".$_GET['jobs']."%'  ORDER BY id DESC;";
    $orderList = mysql_query ($query) or exit("The query could not be performed");
```

May be it help someone.